# Is there a word that means “longing to become a plant”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word that captures the need to become a plant/tree

I know it’s specific but help me out.

Comment: You need to provide context and what you have found in your own research.

Comment: Here I've coined for you: _phytoformalgia_.

Comment: Is this a sexual fetish, a body dysmorphia disorder, a leisure thing like furry conventions, or a desire to be one with all nature, maybe pantheism?

Comment: Ask [Daphne](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0028:book=1:card=452).

Comment: Seeds all have the *urge to grow*.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no single English word for that.